# Travel time from Cusco Airport to Poroy Station

Tags: cusco

Our original flight to Cusco from Lima was canceled and we now arrive at 6:20am.  Is this enough time to get from the airport to Poroy Station for an 8:25am train? I'm assuming after getting our luggage we will most likely leave the airport around 7:00am. We will also have one short stop at the JW Marriott to drop our bags off for storage.   The hotel looks like it's on the way to the station. Thoughts on timing?

Comment: Definitely a risky one since Poroy is way outside of city of Cusco.

Comment: What's your mode of transport ? Rental car? Taxi? Private car ? If everything goes well, you can certainly make it, but there isn't a whole lot of room for errors or mishaps: traffic, flight delay, lost luggage, can't find the driver, etc. Having a working phone certainly would help

Answer (score 2):

Per [Google Maps](https://maps.app.goo.gl/cQTu9qDDZdQGXT6r8), it's a 30–45 minute drive from Cusco airport to the Poroy train station. Cusco is not a huge airport, and there is no need to clear immigration or anything on a flight there from Lima, so you can probably be in a taxi within half an hour or so of landing there.

Combined, this would put you at the train station by 7:30 or 8:00 if all goes well, which meets [PeruRail's suggestion](https://www.perurail.com/trains/expedition/) to arrive 30 minutes early to catch your train.

However, you do not have a ton of slack time for something to go wrong: if your flight is delayed for more than usual, or there is a problem with your baggage, or road works making the drive significantly later than usual, you could be in trouble. Evaluating if the risks are acceptable to you depends on how comfortable you would be making alternate arrangements if you need to.